# Javascript push objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm totally new to objects,

I need to push objects to get this structure:

```
var data = [
            {x: 0, y: 91},
            {x: 1, y: 90},
            {x: 2, y: 89.7},
            {x: 3, y: 89.5},
            {x: 4, y: 89.2},
            {x: 5, y: 88.2},
            {x: 6, y: 88.4},
            {x: 7, y: 87.9},
            {x: 8, y: 87.2},
            {x: 9, y: 87.0},
            {x: 10, y: 87.2},

        ];
```

trying this way

```
for (var i=0; i<result.rows.length; i++) {

var row = result.rows.item(i);

data.push({x: i, y: row.weight});console.log(data[i]);

}
```

here is the jsfiddle example, not the whole code with SQLite database, just the part I am not able to manage, what I am trying to do is to feed the chart dynamically, but looks like I am not able to push the 'data' array in the right way (if the problem is there, because the push code looks good).

http://jsfiddle.net/zeroshadow/WDEUz/3/

that's what I get from the console when I push the data in:

```
Object {x: 1, y: 65} 
Object {x: 2, y: 64.9}
Object {x: 3, y: 64.8}
Object {x: 4, y: 64.2}
Object {x: 5, y: 64.3}
Object {x: 6, y: 64.5}
Object {x: 7, y: 64.3} 
Object {x: 8, y: 64} 
Object {x: 9, y: 63.8}
Object {x: 10, y: 63.1}
```

looks OK but then the chart does not like it and all is vanished. As I have no knowledge of objects, I thought the array after the push has something wrong, because the data array in its initial state works.

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens? Do you see any errors in the console? What is `result`? What is `result.rows`? Even though you have included the code, you haven't provided any other useful information that is necessary to solve whatever problem you have.

Comment: @deemeetree That shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: Just to illustrate my point, I can take the code you posted without any modifications and "make it work": http://jsfiddle.net/E4TLf/. So if what you posted doesn't work for you, it's because `result` or `result.rows` isn't what you think it is, or because of any other problem with code you *didn't* post.

Comment: In the for loop you are checking against the length of result.rows, You want to know how many rows you have in the result, so you check the length of **result.rows**.  You then assign the row variable to **result.rows.item(i)**.  I don't know what item() is, but I would think you want to do **var row = result.rows[i]** to get the correct data object.

Comment: The code is right, nothing wrong with it, it was me overlooking the range settings of the chart, so I was simply pushing data out of the range and the chard couldn't display.

Anyway thanks because knowing the code was good, I was able to look around and discover what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used: `console.log(data[i]);` in the for loop and probably you've saw how objects got pushed into the array. Make sure you `console.log(data)` outside your for loop (just for debugging). Your `data.push({x: i, y: row.weight})` is correct. Maybe row.weight it's not what you think. Also make sure that `result.rows.length` is 10.
You should give us a fiddle or more informations if you need better support.

Comment: Radu thanks for the comment, knowing I was on the right way helped me focusing elsewhere, and I found the bug!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, like often happen I overlooked the data range settings in the chart. My fault my misunderstanding. Sorry again.
The code works.

in the Jsfiddle example you can see:

y = pv.Scale.linear(82, 92).range(0, h);

and I am just pushing data out of the range from 65 to 60. I adjusted the range:

y = pv.Scale.linear(59, 66).range(0, h);

and all is like expected.

Thank you to all and sorry for the waste of time.